# What are some new and emerging programming languages

Tags: programming-languages

What are some new and exciting programming languages? I have already looked at ruby and python. Are there any other languages out there

Comment: Should be on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [atomo](http://atomo-lang.org/) - Erlang-style message passing on Haskell's runtime
- [ANI](http://code.google.com/p/anic/) - dataflow programming
- [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) - a "little language" that compiles to JavaScript
- [Go](http://golang.org/) - Google's systems language
- [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) - Lisp on the JVM
- [F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/default.aspx) - OCaml on CLR/.NET

Answer (score 3):

[Fantom](http://fantom.org/).

- Cross compiles to JVM, CLR, or JavaScript.
- Optional dynamic typing.
- Object Oriented / Functional Programming
- Built-in Actor Model Concurrency
- Built-in JSON serialization

Answer (score 2):

[Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29), developed by Google, for one... :)

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of [F#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29). Don't know if it is exciting though.

Answer (score 1):

- [Factor](http://factorcode.org/)
- [io](http://www.iolanguage.com/)

(Both are, unlike the aforementioned Python and Ruby, inventions that were not created in a prior millennium.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

LOLCODE is pretty new.

Answer (score 0):

I would put in there Silverlight, not a language but kinda new and kinda exciting.  It is something to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I think Mozilla's Rust will have good impact.

There is also Erlang. It's kinda old but its good.

R is great for statistics analysis.